# Is this an upper bound or a lower bound.

Tags: inequality

Which sense of inequality is correct regarding the following expression

$$\big|\sum_{i\leq 3}X_i a_i \big|^2 \stackrel{\leq}{\geq} \sum_{i\leq 3}\big|X_i\big|^2|a_i|^2$$

where we have that $$X_i\in \mathbb{C}$$

So since $X_i$ could be complex... I am guessing $\leq$ is the correct sense? But then I try the example $X_i= a_i=1$, I get that it should be $\geq$...

What do you think .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your inequality as follows:

$$\big|\sum_{i\leq 3}X_i a_i \big|^2 {\leq} \sum_{i\leq 3}\big|X_i\big|^2\sum_{i\leq 3}|a_i|^2$$

Then it is Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for $n=3$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_i X_i a_i\right|^2 & = \left|\left(\sum_i X_i a_i\right)\left(\sum_j X_j a_j \right)\right| \\
& = \left|\sum_i X_i^2 a_i^2 + \sum_{i \neq j} X_i X_j a_i a_j\right|\end{align}$$ From this equation you can see, that there is no definite inequality sign. It might be $\ge$ or $\le$...